# Why is executing two times?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

> This was solved, check the solution by **DBS**

I'm trying to create a drop input like mediafire. I'm having an issue with a **function that repeats two times**.

The message from browser console:

```
se ejecuta la funcion file:13:3
File { name: "8b32cacb0ad946479513721142c7fc9f.jp…", lastModified: 1447114071000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-11-10T00:07:51.000Z, size: 161020, type: "image/jpeg" } file:18:7
fin de bucle file:30:5
se ejecuta la funcion file:13:3
File { name: "8b32cacb0ad946479513721142c7fc9f.jp…", lastModified: 1447114071000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2015-11-10T00:07:51.000Z, size: 161020, type: "image/jpeg" } file:18:7
fin de bucle file:30:5
```

**Code**

```
script.
      var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
      dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
      var miniatures = document.getElementById("miniatures");
      var miniature = document.createElement("div");
      miniature.className = "all-20"; 
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      var files;
      var reader = [];

      // mecanica
      function drop(e){
        console.log("se ejecuta la funcion");
        var dt = e.dataTransfer;
        files = dt.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            var file = files[i];
            console.log(file);
            img.file = file;          
            miniature.appendChild(img);
            miniatures.appendChild(miniature);
            reader[i] = new FileReader();
            reader[i].onload = (function(event){
              return function(e){
                event.src= e.target.result;
              };
            })(img);
            reader[i].readAsDataURL(file);
          }
          console.log('fin de bucle');
      }
```

**HTML**

```
form(action="" enctype="multipart/form-data")
              input(class="all-100 drop ink-droppable align-center fallback" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="dropZone" ondrop="drop(event)")
```

Comment: So, what's the actual problem? I thought you only wanted it to execute once, but then you say `the second is to show miniatures of all dropped files` So I'm not sure what you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I added the HTML section, anyway, the function drop(e) must be executed just one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the drop event twice, once in the HTML and once in the JS.

Remove one of these:

```
ondrop="drop(event)"
```

or

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
dropZone.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
```